# Working with pivot table to access other table information

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot, relationship

I have two tables: `products` and `requests`, a pivot **requests_products** that save the *products_id*, *requests_id* and other two informations.

I also have another table called `requests_observations` that save the `requests_products_id` and an observation for that *product* in that *request*.

In my Requests model I have a `belongsToMany` to Products

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'requests_products')->withTimestamps();
}
```

But what I need to do is to add an observation for a *requests_products_id*, I have a model for this table, but I don't know where I put the ***hasMany***, in Products or Requests model.

Thank you.

***Update***

Product model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'categories_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function fileUpload()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\FileUpload', 'file_upload_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredients', 'products_ingredients')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Requests model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Requests extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function board()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Boards', 'boards_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'status_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'requests_products')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

*requests_products*

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM requests_products;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| requests_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| products_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| unity_price | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| quantity    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| total_price | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

*requests_observations*

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM requests_observations;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| requests_products_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| observation          | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at           | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at           | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to know how do I insert an observation from a requests_products_id and how do I get this information later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with some changes in my code.

I was using `$hidden` in my Request and Product models, and I was hidden the ***pivot***. This was enabling me to call the pivot option when I was accessing the model property.

I also did what ***Marco Feregrino*** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358344/4611395), I added in my Request.php, products() function the option to specify the pivots from that relationship.

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'requests_products')->withPivot('id', 'unity_price', 'quantity', 'total_price')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My final *$hidden* variable is `protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];`

In my Products.php I did not need to change anything.

Now to work with the pivot, I just need to find the correct product, from a request.

```
$productRequest = $request->products()->find($productInformation->id);

// Create the RequestsObservations instance
$requestsObservations = new RequestsObservation();
$requestsObservations->requests_products_id = $productRequest->pivot->id;
$requestsObservations->observation = $productInformation->observation;
$requestsObservations->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 mode** 
This is many to many
//Model Requests

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class());
}
//model Products
public function request()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ModelRequest::class());
}
```

if you have the table requests_observations and has more atrributes you need to do other model RequestsObservations and edit it like normal model

**2d mode**
By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I've updated my question, I added my models and database, I believe that what you answer I already have done, just need to know how to implement the requests_observations in this architecture. Thanks!